# how to solve CORS error in react and django

Tags: javascript, django

i am trying to creat log in app using Django and react .

my js :

```
const client = axios.create({
baseURL: "http://127.0.0.1:8000"});
```

//my submitRegistration function

```
function submitRegistration(e) {
e.preventDefault();
client.post(         //every time I got cors error here//      
  "/api/register",
  {
    email: email,
    username: username,
    password: password
  }
).then(function(res) {
  client.post(
    "/api/login",
    {
      email: email,
      password: password
    }
  ).then(function(res) {
    setCurrentUser(true);
  });
});}
```

django cors setup:

```
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
'http://localhost',
'http://127.0.0.1',
'http://0.0.0.0',      ]  CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
```

I dont know why I got cors error here.any suggestion please!

Comment: You also need to allow the right ports -> `:8000`

Comment: @Reyno hi.
what does it mean?can you explain please

Comment: i did this but its not solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) error typically occurs when making requests from a web application hosted on one domain to a server on another domain. In your case, it seems you are running your Django server on `http://127.0.0.1:8000`, and your React app is hosted on a different localhost port `http://localhost:<your-react-port>`. Also you need to ensure that you add the middleware class `corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware` to listen in on responses:

```py
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    'http://localhost:<your-react-port>',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    ...,
    "corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
    ...,
]
```

Comment: tnx.
i did it but problem is not solved same error.

Comment: i im trying to copy this project can you please check it out if you have kind time.

https://github.com/seankwarren/Django-React-jwt-authentication

Comment: Hey, according to your react app uses port `3000`. Can you please confirm this is what you added`CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGIN = ['http://localhost:3000']` ?

Comment: yes i did.

CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    # 'http://localhost',
    # 'http://127.0.0.1',
    'http://0.0.0.0',
    'http://localhost:3000',
    'http://127.0.0.1:8000',
]

Comment: Can you please share the error you're getting. That will make it easy to help you.

Comment: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/register' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to ..............................

Comment: ERROR
Network Error
AxiosError: Network Error
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:50017:14)
    at Axios.request (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:50469:15)

Comment: App.js:28 
        
        
       GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/user net::ERR_FAILED 403 (Forbidden)

Comment: DId you add `"corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware"` to your settings.MIDDLEWARE?

Comment: ohhh! sorry I forgot to add Corsheaders middleware in settings.
after adding Corsheaders middleware in my settings 
I'm able to log in .
thank you so much

Comment: Glad I could help you, would be nice if you could please mark this as correct so it can help someone else who encounters this same issue.

Answer (score 0):

[django-cors-headers](https://pypi.org/project/django-cors-headers/)

See the example there. You forgot the port (this should be a port of your react application)

```
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
"http://127.0.0.1:8000",
]
```

Comment: tnx for reply.
i added you suggested URL in my cors origins but still error is remaining.

Comment: actually im trying to copy this project .If possible please check it out

https://github.com/seankwarren/Django-React-jwt-authentication

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution

DId you add "corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware" to your settings.MIDDLEWARE? –
Temi